# Interval Computation for Python

Tags: python, dataframe, intervals, computation

need some help on this :)

I have a table like this

| Time | Participant |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-17 15:13:23 | Customer |
| 2023-01-17 15:14:00 | Customer |
| 2023-01-17 15:16:16 | Customer |
| 2023-01-17 15:16:18 | Agent |
| 2023-01-17 15:16:28 | Customer |
| 2023-01-17 15:16:34 | Agent |
| 2023-01-17 15:17:23 | Customer |
| 2023-01-17 15:18:07 | Agent |

Now i want to compute the average delay in the reponse of the agent,
ex like in row 3 we a time stamp of 15:16:16 and the reply of the agent was 2023-01-17 15:16:28 which a 2 seconds delay, plus (2023-01-17 15:16:28 , 2023-01-17 15:16:34) which is 6 seconds and the last interaction is 44 seconds, divided by 3 since the interaction was 3.

1. 2 seconds
2. 6 seconds
3. 44 seconds

total of 52 seconds divided by 3, we got 17.3
17.3 is the average response time

How can I compute this using python?

I really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: Note here that stack-overflow isn't a coding service :)

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the steps you would need to perform are as follows:

1. Store all of the table data in a list of dictionaries like so - `[{time: 2023-01-17 15:13:23, participant:'Customer'}...]`
2. Convert the timestamps to a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object which will help you in the next step.
3. Run basic for loops checking the index of `paricipant:` Agent and the corresponding *last* reply of the customer. With the help of the previous step you are able to subtract the time difference and find the delays.